# Apple Script - How do I check if a window with a specific title exists?

Tags: applescript, automator, catalina

I would like to create an apple script that checks if a window of an application with a specific name (not id or index) exists. I used the following code in a previous script, and it works:

```
tell application "Notes" to close (every window whose name is "Notes")
```

However, I can't figure out how to check if a window with this title exists. This should be incredibly simple. How do I do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the *System Events* application - for example:

```
tell application "System Events"
    if exists (window "Terminal — -zsh" of process "Terminal") then
        display dialog "Found"
    else
        display dialog "Not found"
    end if
end tell
```

Note that *process* is case sensitive while *window* is **not**.  Therefore this will work

`if exists (window "TeRmInAl — -ZsH" of process "Terminal")`

but this will not

`if exists (window "Terminal — -zsh" of process "terminal")`

[image: Script Editor]

If you are running from *Script Editor* you must authorise it in *System Preferences* > *Security & Privacy* > *Privacy* > *Accessibility*

[image: Accessibility]

Comment: Thanks! This all works. I have one more question, however. How to do I detect if a window with a specific name is hidden or not? Also, how do I check if a window with a specific ID is hidden or not? @user3439894

Comment: see above comment.

Comment: @PeterSchorn - that is a separate question, please ask a new one to avoid confusion.  You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10176287/2953889) first.  Essentially if *System Events* finds the window you can do something like `set isHidden to not visible of application process "Word"` for hidden and `set windowDescription to description of window "Document1" of process "Word"` then `if windowDescription = "dialogue" then...` for minimized to dock.  Note "Dialog"/"Dialogue" spelling depends on locale.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is simple and there is no need, in this case, to involve **System Events**. Just ask **Notes** directly if the `window` exists, e.g.:

```
tell application "Notes"
    exists window "Notes"
end tell
```

This returns either `true` or `false`, however the *code* in this form may not be as useful as either wrapping the query in an `if` *statement block* or assigning the results to a *variable*, e.g.:

```
tell application "Notes"
    if exists window "Notes" then
        # Do something.
    else
        # Do something else.
    end if
end tell
```

Or:

```
tell application "Notes"
    set itExists to exists window "Notes"
    if itExists then
        # Do something.
    else
        # Do something else.
    end if
end tell
```

Comment: How do I assign the results to a variable? Could you provide a simple exmaple?

Comment: @Peter Schorn, The second _code block_, the one after "Or:" assigns the result to a _variable_, i.e. `itExists`, and is a _Boolean_, which will be either `true` or `false`.  In other words, if `itExists` is `true` then the _code_ in the _if branch_, the one with the `# Do something.` _comment_, runs, and if `false` the _else branch_,  the one with the `# Do something else.` _comment_, runs.